# ssh connections are spawning hundreds of ssh-agent /bin/bash instances

Tags: linux, ssh, archlinux

I have an Arch server running on a VMWare VM.  I connect to it through a Firewall that forwards ssh connections from port X to port 22 on the server.  Yesterday, I started receiving the error "Bash: Fork: Resource Temporarily Unavailable".  I can log in as root and manage things without problem, but it seems that when I ssh in as the user I normally use, the ssh session is now spawning hundreds of ssh-agent /bin/bash sessions.  This is, in turn, using up all the threads and file descriptors (from what I can tell) on the system and making it unusable.  The little bit of info I've been able to find thus far tells me that I must have some sort of loop, but this hasn't happened until yesterday, possibly when I ran updates.  At this point, I am open to suggestions.

Comment: See if something in your shell startup files is actually spawning a shell (i.e. recursively).

Comment: I don't see anything.  I just found that in the .x2GO directory, there are a bunch of symbolic links to /tmp.  The files in there are all ssh socket files.  X2G0 is using ssh to connect to the server as well.  But I've duplicated the problem with regular ssh connections via command line.

Comment: Turns out you were correct.  I removed the line in my .bashrc for ssh-agent /bin/bash and the solved the problem.  I've been using this server for months without problems and haven't touched that file since installation, so I'm not sure why it was a problem.  But that fixed it.  Thank you!

Comment: I'm turning that into an answer then...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of your shell initialization files is probably spawning a shell, which, when reading the shell initialization files will spawn a shell, etc.

You mentioned `ssh-agent /bin/bash`. Putting *this* in `.bashrc` will definitely cause problems, as this instructs `ssh-agent` to spawn `bash`...

Instead, use something like

```
if [[ -z "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ]]; then
  eval $(ssh-agent)
fi
```

in `.bashrc` (or `.xinitrc` *or* `.xsession` for systems with graphical logins).

Or possibly (untested):

```
if [[ -z "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ]]; then
  ssh-agent /bin/bash
fi
```

in `.bash_profile`.

Answer (score 0):

in my case (windows) it was because i was not exiting when done with a shell, so they were not getting disposed.

when done use `ctrl+d` or type `exit` to terminate the ssh agent